# Are controller factories neccessary when using Ninject in ASP.NET mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, ninject

I am at a loss of what to do with the multitude of documentation available through google in .net as regards using Ninject with asp.net mvc 4

First of all, i want to know if Controller factories are neccessary in asp.net.

Also, is constructor injection really the only way we can do dependency injection with MVC 4 because property injection and method injection does not seem to work when i use them with my controllers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not an expert on `Ninject` but as far as i know, i am only using it to link my `DataSource Interface` and my `EfDb Class` to the rest of my application.

If you need a good book that has a Real Application built around `Ninject` try:
[Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework, Third Edition](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/1430234040/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d6_i6?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=1T5D5MNTD73VFSFWM0FR&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1375922682&pf_rd_i=915398)

or

[Pro Asp.Net Mvc 4](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/1430242361/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d6_i2?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1T5D5MNTD73VFSFWM0FR&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1375923922&pf_rd_i=915398)

There are very few lines of code i am usually concerned with

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
                   ? null
                   : (IController) ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IDataSource>().To<EfDb>();
    }
}
```

Then register your `NinjectControllerFactory` in `Global.asax.cs` with:

`ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());`

As you can see, this class use `Method Injection` using `private void AddBindings()`. This makes it very easy if you are following `Test Driven Development (TDD)`

Comment: But i read somewhere that if u your application inherited from NinjectHttpApplication and override the appropriate methods, controllers will automatically have dependencies statisfied via IOC Container.

Comment: @PeterEdike Everyone has they own way of writing code, this game is all about picking up a style that works and improving it on the way. I would suggest you read one of those books i mentioned.

Comment: I dont know much about this but this code work fine.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation here:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-controllers, "The only thing that has to be done is to configure the Ninject bindings for its dependencies. The controller itself will be found by Ninject even without adding a binding."

NInject will automagically set up your controller dependencies (provided it has a binding for those types).

Comment: I am using MVC5/WebApi2 and this method did not work for me. @Komengem 's suggestion worked.